# URL Rewrite problem

Tags: apache, url, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I did a .htaccess that change urls like www.site.com/sell.php to www.site.com/sell. Sell page exists at my / and it works fine. The problem is when i try something like www.site.com/sadasdasdasdadsdfgfds, because "sadasdasdasdadsdfgfds" doesn't exist. I receive a 500 Apache's error.

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /$0.php
```

How could I fix it? Thank you guys.

UPDATE: Worked! Thanks guys!
Now how do I redirect user to a 404 custom error page?

Comment: For sure there must be some clever guys here that will help you. But, you can consider posting this to http://serverfault.com where there are a bunch of server-specialists guys.

Comment: ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

that's all there is to custom error pages

Answer (score 1):

You have checks to make sure the file doesn't exist. You also have to make sure the corresponding php-file does exist:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .* /$0.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to test if the new destination is an existing file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .* /$0.php
```

Otherwise you will get an infinite recursion.